# abstract class, child class not overriding method

Tags: java

i searched a lot before posting this question but all i got was more questions to be answered. I'm new to java so my question might be easy 
Anyway my problem is this: 
That's my super class

```
    public abstract class Shape 
{

   protected String color;


   // Constructor
   public Shape (String color) 
   {
        this.color = color;
   }

   public String toString() 
   {
        return "Color = " + color;
   }


   abstract double getArea();
}
```

That's my child class:

```
    public class Rectangle extends Shape 
{
    private int width;
    private int length;


   // Constructor
   public Rectangle(String color, int length, int width) 
   {
      super(color);
      this.length = length;
      this.width = width;
   }


   public String toString() 
   {
      return  "color = " + color + "\nlength = " + this.length + "\nwidth = " + this.width;
   }
   public double getArea() 
   {
        return length*width;
   }


}
```

And the main code:

```
    public class TestShape 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        Shape a = new Rectangle("RED",10,5);
        a.getArea();

   }
}
```

My problem is that although it compiles fine, i get no results back and i wonder why my method in child class doesn't override the method of the abstract class. Any help is appreciated cause

Comment: If you had a system.out.print around your call to get area you would see output

Comment: Probably you get back the area, but you don't use it, i.e. you dot print it.

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(a.getArea());` What do you get?

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks a lot. Like i said i'm a noob!

Comment: System.out.println(a.getArea()); gives you 50.0

Comment: Make sure you put the `@Override` annotation over `getArea()` in your `Rectangle` class. Some IDE's won't compile without correctly using this, and is always a very good idea to do to help those who have to look at your code (including yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that although it compiles fine, I get no results back

You need to add in a print statement to print the result of the method call back to the console, so `System.out.println(a.getArea());`

> and I wonder why my method in child class doesn't override the method of the abstract class.

It does as it is (as is the `toString()` method as well from the `Object` class). If it didn't, the compiler would throw a error saying that not all the abstract methods from the abstract class were implemented (this would also be the case if you were implementing an Interface).

However, it is good practice to add in the `@Override` annotation above the method to signal that the method is overridden. IDEs like Eclipse or Netbeans should add this in for you automatically.